# Center GridView in Relative layout

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/photo_browser_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="none"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
    android:columnWidth="100dp">
</GridView>
```

I want to centre my GridView inside Relative layout. My spacing is always fixed. In result I have GridView aligned to left. How can I center it inside parent?

[image: GridView]

Comment: Try using `android-stretchMode`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For GridView in the layout, `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` conflicts with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. It means : to calculate how many columns to form, width is required, but to find width we need how many columns to wrap around, a circular dependency.

You can use [`android:stretchMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3astretchMode) to let columns fill up empty space.